# Any fun baby/toddler apps for Mac?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, games, children

As soon as my two-year-old notices I turn my MacBook Pro on she jumps in my lap and wants to bang on the keyboard.

I need recommendations for fun applications that would allow my toddler to play with the computer for a couple of minutes and that keeps those little hands from messing up with my other applications and files.

What I'm looking for:

- Applications for Mac only. Sadly, it seems like almost every toddler application these days is made for the iPad.
- Fullscreen right from startup, with a hard-to-press-by-accident key sequence to exit fullscreen or quit the app. Basically, like a screensaver in that regard.
- Not a game, at least not a challenging one. A two year old don't care if she wins or loses and doesn't want to start and retry levels, but just wants to have fun for some indeterminate period of time banging the keys to some cute noises and animations.
- Keyboard responsiveness. Banging the keys should make noises and have some visual response.

Some nice-to-haves:

- No text reading or typing necessary to play.
- Not very centered around mouse/trackpad input. It's relatively hard for a two year old to control the mouse cursor with precision. It should be OK if the application responds to trackpad clicks, but it should not require the user to click a small half-inch button with the mouse cursor in order to make things happen.

I don't care about:

- Free or paid.
- App Store or classic download.

The closest I have found is [BabyView](http://heybearproductionsblog.blogspot.mx/), which is clearly not designed for the Mac but for touch devices and therefore doesn't respond to keyboard input at all.

Answer (score 2):

AlphaBaby http://alphababy.sourceforge.net

But I do feel that Google is, in this case, your friend. Try, toddler games OS X. Older OS X games work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late on this one, but I have a 6 year old daughter who wants to do stuff on my big Mac too, so I made a fun and educational game for her: Happy Cook- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/happy-cook/id1052538652?mt=12 I also take it to go for her on my Android but it's also available on iOS and Window Phones. You can take a look too if you want it on other platforms http://greyheadstudio.com/happy-cook/ .

It's honestly one of her favorites. I wanted it to be nice and colorful with comfortable sounds in the background.

Let me know what you think if you check it out!